# How my form_tag in ruby can accept my def REGEX (in application helper)?

Tags: regex, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an email search bar in my page. When I put the `+` character in my `text_field`, the email isn't found.

For example, searching for `test123@gmail.com` works, but searching for `test+123@gmail.com` doesn't work.

My form code:

```rb
<%= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get', local: true, class: 'ui form' do %>
  <div class="fields">
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag "Search by email:" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    </div>
    <div id="search-bar-button-users", class="field">
      <button class="ui labeled icon button">
        <i class="search icon"></i>
          Search
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My ApplicationHelper:

```rb
def is_a_valid_email?(email)
  (email =~ /^(([A-Za-z0-9]*\.+*_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\+))*[A-Z‌​a-z0-9]+@{1}((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i)
end
```

I would like the search bar to ignore the `+` and still find the email.

Comment: Try this : `email =~ /^(([A-Za-z0-9]*\.+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\+))*[A-Z‌​a-z0-9]+@{1}((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i`

Comment: thanks, but I need to put code in my form_tag no? Actually the def isn't linked to my form_tag search field I think ?

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/the-100-correct-way-to-validate-email-addresses-7c4818f24643 is an interesting read.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to work direct in rails is to correct the email before searching.

In your controller

```
def correct_email(email)
  email.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z@.]/, '') # only keep 0-9 , A-Z, a-z, '.' and '@'
end
```

Then

```
User.where(email: correct_email(params[:search]))
```

Comment: Thank, but with your help, I only can verify the email. I just want to "bypass" the "+" character when the search is sent

Comment: It's not only verifying. Let say you have email `test123@gmail.com` in your db. Your pass `test+123@gmail.com` as search params, using `User.where(email: correct_email(params[:search]))` can find your email @AwsmDev

Comment: Thank you for your help, but where can I insert 'User where'? I have to insert it in this line? "<% = text_field_tag: search, params [: search]%>"